# Cannot add title to org-mode document

Tags: org-mode

I tried to add a title to my document as below :
[image]

But when I export the document to html (`C-c C-e h o`), i get the error stated at the bottom of the image. What can I do ?

Emacs version (Windows) : GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2016-09-17

Org-mode version : Org mode version 9.0.5

Comment: You'll want to give your org-mode and emacs versions.

Comment: works for me with GNU Emacs 25.2.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.10) org-version 9.0.6 Maybe delete the mode line, just invoke org mode with M-x if you want the end of the name to be .txt and then refresh the header by having cursor there and C-c C-c

Comment: Set `debug-on-error` to `t`, rerun the export and post the backtrace on the org-mode mailing list. Or update org-mode to the most recent version and try again. And please post the org file itself in the question: that way people can cut and paste it into their emacs and try it out: posting images makes that impossible.

Comment: Works for me with Org mode version 9.0.5 (release_9.0.5-444-g998576 @ /home/nick/elisp/org-mode/lisp/);
GNU Emacs 26.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.20.10) of 2017-04-14