# Cannot add #+TITLE to org file and export to HTML on org v9.1.9

Tags: emacs, org-mode

This question is the same as [Cannot add title to org-mode document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43730192/cannot-add-title-to-org-mode-document) but the answers given there do not help.

This file fails:

```
#+TITLE: This title breaks

* Intro

  This file cannot be exported to HTML
```

- Emacs version: "GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0, NS appkit-1504.83 Version 10.12.6 (Build 16G1036))  of 2018-04-10"
- Org version: "9.1.9"

The `debug-on-error` backtrace is as shown:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp #("This title breaks" 0 17 (:parent (#1))))
  org-element-set-contents(#("This title breaks" 0 17 (:parent (#0))))
  apply(org-element-set-contents #("This title breaks" 0 17 (:parent (#0))) nil)
  #[257 "\211\305\306\307#\310\311\211:\204\312\202\"\n@9\203!\nAA\202\"\n)\"\210\313\314  \211:\2043\312\202@\n@9\203?\nAA\202@\n)#\210\315\211 \n;\203V\316\317\n#\202\\\320\nA@\"*\211;\203n\321\n\312\f$\202z\nA\322\nA@\f#\240\210\n+\210    AA@\240\210    @\240*\207" [new old element property value replace-regexp-in-string "\n" " " mapc #[(blob) "\305 \211;\203\306\f\307\n$\202 \fA\310\fA@\n#\240\210\f+\207" [blob old value property element :parent org-add-props nil plist-put] 6] nil apply org-element-set-contents :parent get-text-property 0 plist-get org-add-props plist-put] 7 "\n\n(fn S)"](#("This title breaks" 0 17 (:parent (#0))))
  #[257 "\211\211:\204\211;\205\311\262\202\211@9\205\211@\262?\206\301\203-\312\301\313\">\206\211\2049\314\310\242\"\202\211\315=\203]\314\310\242\211:\204N\316\262\202Y\211@9\203Y\211AA\262\"\202\211\304>\203~\300!\211\203}\302\203v\317\320\"\210\202}\307\307\242B\240\210\210\306\321=\203\271;\204\271\211\236A\211\203\270\211@\310\242\211;\203\247\322\323#\266\202\202\257\312A@\"\266\202!\210A\266\202\202\216\210\303\203\377\306\321=\203\377\316\211:\204\326\211;\205\336\311\262\202\340\211@9\205\336\211@\262\206\375\324\211;\203\365\322\323#\266\202\202\375\312A@\"\266\202>\203\325\202r>\203\326\202r\315=\203\326\202r\311=\203'\325\202r\204/\325\202r\211\2047\326\202r\211\211:\204H\211;\205P\311\262\202R\211@9\205P\211@\262\211\204Z\325\202p\211>\203e\325\202p\327!\203o\325\202p\326\262\266\204\326=\203\377\211\203\376\211@\211@A\211;\203\225\322\323#\266\202\202\235\312A@\"\266\202\211\203\365 \235\203\336!\235\203\317\330!\211\203\313\211@\310\242A!\210\310\242@!\210A\266\202\202\262\210\202\365\310\242A!\210\310\242@!\210\202\365!\235\203\360\314\310\242\330!\"\210\202\365\310\242!\210\266A\266\202\202{\210\211\305>\206\211:\204\316\262\202\211@9\203\211AA\262?\206\306\331=\203.\211\">?\206\306\332=\203\352\316\211:\204G\211;\205O\311\262\202Q\211@9\205O\211@\262\206n\324\211;\203f\322\323#\266\202\202n\312A@\"\266\202>\203y\325\202\343>\203\204\326\202\343\315=\203\216\326\202\343\311=\203\230\325\202\343\204\240\325\202\343\211\204\250\326\202\343\211\211:\204\271\211;\205\301\311\262\202\303\211@9\205\301\211@\262\211\204\313\325\202\341\211>\203\326\325\202\341\327!\203\340\325\202\341\326\262\266\204\325=\206\314\310\242\211:\204\371\316\262\202\211@9\203\211AA\262\"\207" [#[257 "\211\305\306\307#\310\311\211:\204\312\202\"\n@9\203!\nAA\202\"\n)\"\210\313\314  \211:\2043\312\202@\n@9\203?\nAA\202@\n)#\210\315\211 \n;\203V\316\317\n#\202\\\320\nA@\"*\211;\203n\321\n\312\f$\202z\nA\322\nA@\f#\240\210\n+\210    AA@\240\210    @\240*\207" [new old element property value replace-regexp-in-string "\n" " " mapc #[(blob) "\305 \211;\203\306\f\307\n$\202 \fA\310\fA@\n#\240\210\f+\207" [blob old value property element :parent org-add-props nil plist-put] 6] nil apply org-element-set-contents :parent get-text-property 0 plist-get org-add-props plist-put] 7 "\n\n(fn S)"] nil nil nil (plain-text) nil objects (nil) (#0) plain-text plist-get :ignore-list mapc org-data nil throw :--map-first-match objects get-text-property 0 :parent object element org-element-secondary-p reverse greater-elements elements org-element-secondary-value-alist org-element-all-objects org-element-all-elements org-element-object-containers org-element--parsed-properties-alist org-element-dual-keywords org-element-multiple-keywords org-element-greater-elements] 11 "\n\n(fn --DATA)"](#("This title breaks" 0 17 (:parent (#0))))
  mapc(#[257 "\211\211:\204\211;\205\311\262\202\211@9\205\211@\262?\206\301\203-\312\301\313\">\206\211\2049\314\310\242\"\202\211\315=\203]\314\310\242\211:\204N\316\262\202Y\211@9\203Y\211AA\262\"\202\211\304>\203~\300!\211\203}\302\203v\317\320\"\210\202}\307\307\242B\240\210\210\306\321=\203\271;\204\271\211\236A\211\203\270\211@\310\242\211;\203\247\322\323#\266\202\202\257\312A@\"\266\202!\210A\266\202\202\216\210\303\203\377\306\321=\203\377\316\211:\204\326\211;\205\336\311\262\202\340\211@9\205\336\211@\262\206\375\324\211;\203\365\322\323#\266\202\202\375\312A@\"\266\202>\203\325\202r>\203\326\202r\315=\203\326\202r\311=\203'\325\202r\204/\325\202r\211\2047\326\202r\211\211:\204H\211;\205P\311\262\202R\211@9\205P\211@\262\211\204Z\325\202p\211>\203e\325\202p\327!\203o\325\202p\326\262\266\204\326=\203\377\211\203\376\211@\211@A\211;\203\225\322\323#\266\202\202\235\312A@\"\266\202\211\203\365 \235\203\336!\235\203\317\330!\211\203\313\211@\310\242A!\210\310\242@!\210A\266\202\202\262\210\202\365\310\242A!\210\310\242@!\210\202\365!\235\203\360\314\310\242\330!\"\210\202\365\310\242!\210\266A\266\202\202{\210\211\305>\206\211:\204\316\262\202\211@9\203\211AA\262?\206\306\331=\203.\211\">?\206\306\332=\203\352\316\211:\204G\211;\205O\311\262\202Q\211@9\205O\211@\262\206n\324\211;\203f\322\323#\266\202\202n\312A@\"\266\202>\203y\325\202\343>\203\204\326\202\343\315=\203\216\326\202\343\311=\203\230\325\202\343\204\240\325\202\343\211\204\250\326\202\343\211\211:\204\271\211;\205\301\311\262\202\303\211@9\205\301\211@\262\211\204\313\325\202\341\211>\203\326\325\202\341\327!\203\340\325\202\341\326\262\266\204\325=\206\314\310\242\211:\204\371\316\262\202\211@9\203\211AA\262\"\207" [#[257 "\211\305\306\307#\310\311\211:\204\312\202\"\n@9\203!\nAA\202\"\n)\"\210\313\314 \211:\2043\312\202@\n@9\203?\nAA\202@\n)#\210\315\211 \n;\203V\316\317\n#\202\\\320\nA@\"*\211;\203n\321\n\312\f$\202z\nA\322\nA@\f#\240\210\n+\210    AA@\240\210    @\240*\207" [new old element property value replace-regexp-in-string "\n" " " mapc #[(blob) "\305 \211;\203\306\f\307\n$\202 \fA\310\fA@\n#\240\210\f+\207" [blob old value property element :parent org-add-props nil plist-put] 6] nil apply org-element-set-contents :parent get-text-property 0 plist-get org-add-props plist-put] 7 "\n\n(fn S)"] nil nil nil (plain-text) nil objects (nil) (#0) plain-text plist-get :ignore-list mapc org-data nil throw :--map-first-match objects get-text-property 0 :parent object element org-element-secondary-p reverse greater-elements elements org-element-secondary-value-alist org-element-all-objects org-element-all-elements org-element-object-containers org-element--parsed-properties-alist org-element-dual-keywords org-element-multiple-keywords org-element-greater-elements] 11 "\n\n(fn --DATA)"] (#("This title breaks" 0 17 (:parent #0))))
  #[257 "\211\211:\204\211;\205\311\262\202\211@9\205\211@\262?\206\301\203-\312\301\313\">\206\211\2049\314\310\242\"\202\211\315=\203]\314\310\242\211:\204N\316\262\202Y\211@9\203Y\211AA\262\"\202\211\304>\203~\300!\211\203}\302\203v\317\320\"\210\202}\307\307\242B\240\210\210\306\321=\203\271;\204\271\211\236A\211\203\270\211@\310\242\211;\203\247\322\323#\266\202\202\257\312A@\"\266\202!\210A\266\202\202\216\210\303\203\377\306\321=\203\377\316\211:\204\326\211;\205\336\311\262\202\340\211@9\205\336\211@\262\206\375\324\211;\203\365\322\323#\266\202\202\375\312A@\"\266\202>\203\325\202r>\203\326\202r\315=\203\326\202r\311=\203'\325\202r\204/\325\202r\211\2047\326\202r\211\211:\204H\211;\205P\311\262\202R\211@9\205P\211@\262\211\204Z\325\202p\211>\203e\325\202p\327!\203o\325\202p\326\262\266\204\326=\203\377\211\203\376\211@\211@A\211;\203\225\322\323#\266\202\202\235\312A@\"\266\202\211\203\365 \235\203\336!\235\203\317\330!\211\203\313\211@\310\242A!\210\310\242@!\210A\266\202\202\262\210\202\365\310\242A!\210\310\242@!\210\202\365!\235\203\360\314\310\242\330!\"\210\202\365\310\242!\210\266A\266\202\202{\210\211\305>\206\211:\204\316\262\202\211@9\203\211AA\262?\206\306\331=\203.\211\">?\206\306\332=\203\352\316\211:\204G\211;\205O\311\262\202Q\211@9\205O\211@\262\206n\324\211;\203f\322\323#\266\202\202n\312A@\"\266\202>\203y\325\202\343>\203\204\326\202\343\315=\203\216\326\202\343\311=\203\230\325\202\343\204\240\325\202\343\211\204\250\326\202\343\211\211:\204\271\211;\205\301\311\262\202\303\211@9\205\301\211@\262\211\204\313\325\202\341\211>\203\326\325\202\341\327!\203\340\325\202\341\326\262\266\204\325=\206\314\310\242\211:\204\371\316\262\202\211@9\203\211AA\262\"\207" [#[257 "\211\305\306\307#\310\311\211:\204\312\202\"\n@9\203!\nAA\202\"\n)\"\210\313\314  \211:\2043\312\202@\n@9\203?\nAA\202@\n)#\210\315\211 \n;\203V\316\317\n#\202\\\320\nA@\"*\211;\203n\321\n\312\f$\202z\nA\322\nA@\f#\240\210\n+\210    AA@\240\210    @\240*\207" [new old element property value replace-regexp-in-string "\n" " " mapc #[(blob) "\305 \211;\203\306\f\307\n$\202 \fA\310\fA@\n#\240\210\f+\207" [blob old value property element :parent org-add-props nil plist-put] 6] nil apply org-element-set-contents :parent get-text-property 0 plist-get org-add-props plist-put] 7 "\n\n(fn S)"] nil nil nil (plain-text) nil objects (nil) (#0) plain-text plist-get :ignore-list mapc org-data nil throw :--map-first-match objects get-text-property 0 :parent object element org-element-secondary-p reverse greater-elements elements org-element-secondary-value-alist org-element-all-objects org-element-all-elements org-element-object-containers org-element--parsed-properties-alist org-element-dual-keywords org-element-multiple-keywords org-element-greater-elements] 11 "\n\n(fn --DATA)"]((#("This title breaks" 0 17 (:parent #0))))
  org-element-map((#("This title breaks" 0 17 (:parent #0))) plain-text #[257 "\211\305\306\307#\310\311\211:\204\312\202\"\n@9\203!\nAA\202\"\n)\"\210\313\314    \211:\2043\312\202@\n@9\203?\nAA\202@\n)#\210\315\211 \n;\203V\316\317\n#\202\\\320\nA@\"*\211;\203n\321\n\312\f$\202z\nA\322\nA@\f#\240\210\n+\210    AA@\240\210    @\240*\207" [new old element property value replace-regexp-in-string "\n" " " mapc #[(blob) "\305 \211;\203\306\f\307\n$\202 \fA\310\fA@\n#\240\210\f+\207" [blob old value property element :parent org-add-props nil plist-put] 6] nil apply org-element-set-contents :parent get-text-property 0 plist-get org-add-props plist-put] 7 "\n\n(fn S)"])
  org-export--get-inbuffer-options([cl-struct-org-export-backend html nil ((bold . org-html-bold) (center-block . org-html-center-block) (clock . org-html-clock) (code . org-html-code) (drawer . org-html-drawer) (dynamic-block . org-html-dynamic-block) (entity . org-html-entity) (example-block . org-html-example-block) (export-block . org-html-export-block) (export-snippet . org-html-export-snippet) (fixed-width . org-html-fixed-width) (footnote-definition . org-html-footnote-definition) (footnote-reference . org-html-footnote-reference) (headline . org-html-headline) (horizontal-rule . org-html-horizontal-rule) (inline-src-block . org-html-inline-src-block) (inlinetask . org-html-inlinetask) (inner-template . org-html-inner-template) (italic . org-html-italic) (item . org-html-item) (keyword . org-html-keyword) (latex-environment . org-html-latex-environment) (latex-fragment . org-html-latex-fragment) (line-break . org-html-line-break) (link . org-html-link) (node-property . org-html-node-property) (paragraph . org-html-paragraph) (plain-list . org-html-plain-list) (plain-text . org-html-plain-text) (planning . org-html-planning) (property-drawer . org-html-property-drawer) (quote-block . org-html-quote-block) (radio-target . org-html-radio-target) (section . org-html-section) (special-block . org-html-special-block) (src-block . org-html-src-block) (statistics-cookie . org-html-statistics-cookie) (strike-through . org-html-strike-through) (subscript . org-html-subscript) (superscript . org-html-superscript) (table . org-html-table) (table-cell . org-html-table-cell) (table-row . org-html-table-row) (target . org-html-target) (template . org-html-template) (timestamp . org-html-timestamp) (underline . org-html-underline) (verbatim . org-html-verbatim) (verse-block . org-html-verse-block)) ((:html-doctype "HTML_DOCTYPE" nil org-html-doctype) (:html-container "HTML_CONTAINER" nil org-html-container-element) (:description "DESCRIPTION" nil nil newline) (:keywords "KEYWORDS" nil nil space) (:html-html5-fancy nil "html5-fancy" org-html-html5-fancy) (:html-link-use-abs-url nil "html-link-use-abs-url" org-html-link-use-abs-url) (:html-link-home "HTML_LINK_HOME" nil org-html-link-home) (:html-link-up "HTML_LINK_UP" nil org-html-link-up) (:html-mathjax "HTML_MATHJAX" nil "" space) (:html-postamble nil "html-postamble" org-html-postamble) (:html-preamble nil "html-preamble" org-html-preamble) (:html-head "HTML_HEAD" nil org-html-head newline) (:html-head-extra "HTML_HEAD_EXTRA" nil org-html-head-extra newline) (:subtitle "SUBTITLE" nil nil parse) (:html-head-include-default-style nil "html-style" org-html-head-include-default-style) (:html-head-include-scripts nil "html-scripts" org-html-head-include-scripts) (:html-allow-name-attribute-in-anchors nil nil org-html-allow-name-attribute-in-anchors) (:html-divs nil nil org-html-divs) (:html-checkbox-type nil nil org-html-checkbox-type) (:html-extension nil nil org-html-extension) (:html-footnote-format nil nil org-html-footnote-format) (:html-footnote-separator nil nil org-html-footnote-separator) (:html-footnotes-section nil nil org-html-footnotes-section) (:html-format-drawer-function nil nil org-html-format-drawer-function) (:html-format-headline-function nil nil org-html-format-headline-function) (:html-format-inlinetask-function nil nil org-html-format-inlinetask-function) (:html-home/up-format nil nil org-html-home/up-format) (:html-indent nil nil org-html-indent) (:html-infojs-options nil nil org-html-infojs-options) (:html-infojs-template nil nil org-html-infojs-template) (:html-inline-image-rules nil nil org-html-inline-image-rules) (:html-link-org-files-as-html nil nil org-html-link-org-files-as-html) (:html-mathjax-options nil nil org-html-mathjax-options) (:html-mathjax-template nil nil org-html-mathjax-template) (:html-metadata-timestamp-format nil nil org-html-metadata-timestamp-format) (:html-postamble-format nil nil org-html-postamble-format) (:html-preamble-format nil nil org-html-preamble-format) (:html-table-align-individual-fields nil nil org-html-table-align-individual-fields) (:html-table-caption-above nil nil org-html-table-caption-above) (:html-table-data-tags nil nil org-html-table-data-tags) (:html-table-header-tags nil nil org-html-table-header-tags) (:html-table-use-header-tags-for-first-column nil nil org-html-table-use-header-tags-for-first-column) (:html-tag-class-prefix nil nil org-html-tag-class-prefix) (:html-text-markup-alist nil nil org-html-text-markup-alist) (:html-todo-kwd-class-prefix nil nil org-html-todo-kwd-class-prefix) (:html-toplevel-hlevel nil nil org-html-toplevel-hlevel) (:html-use-infojs nil nil org-html-use-infojs) (:html-validation-link nil nil org-html-validation-link) (:html-viewport nil nil org-html-viewport) (:html-inline-images nil nil org-html-inline-images) ...) ((:filter-options . org-html-infojs-install-script) (:filter-parse-tree . org-html-image-link-filter) (:filter-final-output . org-html-final-function)) nil (104 "Export to HTML" ((72 "As HTML buffer" org-html-export-as-html) (104 "As HTML file" org-html-export-to-html) (111 "As HTML file and open" (lambda (a s v b) (if a (org-html-export-to-html t s v b) (org-open-file (org-html-export-to-html nil s v b)))))))])
  org-export-get-environment([cl-struct-org-export-backend html nil ((bold . org-html-bold) (center-block . org-html-center-block) (clock . org-html-clock) (code . org-html-code) (drawer . org-html-drawer) (dynamic-block . org-html-dynamic-block) (entity . org-html-entity) (example-block . org-html-example-block) (export-block . org-html-export-block) (export-snippet . org-html-export-snippet) (fixed-width . org-html-fixed-width) (footnote-definition . org-html-footnote-definition) (footnote-reference . org-html-footnote-reference) (headline . org-html-headline) (horizontal-rule . org-html-horizontal-rule) (inline-src-block . org-html-inline-src-block) (inlinetask . org-html-inlinetask) (inner-template . org-html-inner-template) (italic . org-html-italic) (item . org-html-item) (keyword . org-html-keyword) (latex-environment . org-html-latex-environment) (latex-fragment . org-html-latex-fragment) (line-break . org-html-line-break) (link . org-html-link) (node-property . org-html-node-property) (paragraph . org-html-paragraph) (plain-list . org-html-plain-list) (plain-text . org-html-plain-text) (planning . org-html-planning) (property-drawer . org-html-property-drawer) (quote-block . org-html-quote-block) (radio-target . org-html-radio-target) (section . org-html-section) (special-block . org-html-special-block) (src-block . org-html-src-block) (statistics-cookie . org-html-statistics-cookie) (strike-through . org-html-strike-through) (subscript . org-html-subscript) (superscript . org-html-superscript) (table . org-html-table) (table-cell . org-html-table-cell) (table-row . org-html-table-row) (target . org-html-target) (template . org-html-template) (timestamp . org-html-timestamp) (underline . org-html-underline) (verbatim . org-html-verbatim) (verse-block . org-html-verse-block)) ((:html-doctype "HTML_DOCTYPE" nil org-html-doctype) (:html-container "HTML_CONTAINER" nil org-html-container-element) (:description "DESCRIPTION" nil nil newline) (:keywords "KEYWORDS" nil nil space) (:html-html5-fancy nil "html5-fancy" org-html-html5-fancy) (:html-link-use-abs-url nil "html-link-use-abs-url" org-html-link-use-abs-url) (:html-link-home "HTML_LINK_HOME" nil org-html-link-home) (:html-link-up "HTML_LINK_UP" nil org-html-link-up) (:html-mathjax "HTML_MATHJAX" nil "" space) (:html-postamble nil "html-postamble" org-html-postamble) (:html-preamble nil "html-preamble" org-html-preamble) (:html-head "HTML_HEAD" nil org-html-head newline) (:html-head-extra "HTML_HEAD_EXTRA" nil org-html-head-extra newline) (:subtitle "SUBTITLE" nil nil parse) (:html-head-include-default-style nil "html-style" org-html-head-include-default-style) (:html-head-include-scripts nil "html-scripts" org-html-head-include-scripts) (:html-allow-name-attribute-in-anchors nil nil org-html-allow-name-attribute-in-anchors) (:html-divs nil nil org-html-divs) (:html-checkbox-type nil nil org-html-checkbox-type) (:html-extension nil nil org-html-extension) (:html-footnote-format nil nil org-html-footnote-format) (:html-footnote-separator nil nil org-html-footnote-separator) (:html-footnotes-section nil nil org-html-footnotes-section) (:html-format-drawer-function nil nil org-html-format-drawer-function) (:html-format-headline-function nil nil org-html-format-headline-function) (:html-format-inlinetask-function nil nil org-html-format-inlinetask-function) (:html-home/up-format nil nil org-html-home/up-format) (:html-indent nil nil org-html-indent) (:html-infojs-options nil nil org-html-infojs-options) (:html-infojs-template nil nil org-html-infojs-template) (:html-inline-image-rules nil nil org-html-inline-image-rules) (:html-link-org-files-as-html nil nil org-html-link-org-files-as-html) (:html-mathjax-options nil nil org-html-mathjax-options) (:html-mathjax-template nil nil org-html-mathjax-template) (:html-metadata-timestamp-format nil nil org-html-metadata-timestamp-format) (:html-postamble-format nil nil org-html-postamble-format) (:html-preamble-format nil nil org-html-preamble-format) (:html-table-align-individual-fields nil nil org-html-table-align-individual-fields) (:html-table-caption-above nil nil org-html-table-caption-above) (:html-table-data-tags nil nil org-html-table-data-tags) (:html-table-header-tags nil nil org-html-table-header-tags) (:html-table-use-header-tags-for-first-column nil nil org-html-table-use-header-tags-for-first-column) (:html-tag-class-prefix nil nil org-html-tag-class-prefix) (:html-text-markup-alist nil nil org-html-text-markup-alist) (:html-todo-kwd-class-prefix nil nil org-html-todo-kwd-class-prefix) (:html-toplevel-hlevel nil nil org-html-toplevel-hlevel) (:html-use-infojs nil nil org-html-use-infojs) (:html-validation-link nil nil org-html-validation-link) (:html-viewport nil nil org-html-viewport) (:html-inline-images nil nil org-html-inline-images) ...) ((:filter-options . org-html-infojs-install-script) (:filter-parse-tree . org-html-image-link-filter) (:filter-final-output . org-html-final-function)) nil (104 "Export to HTML" ((72 "As HTML buffer" org-html-export-as-html) (104 "As HTML file" org-html-export-to-html) (111 "As HTML file and open" (lambda (a s v b) (if a (org-html-export-to-html t s v b) (org-open-file (org-html-export-to-html nil s v b)))))))] nil nil)
  org-export-as(html nil nil nil nil)
  org-export-to-buffer(html "*Org HTML Export*" nil nil nil nil nil #[0 "\300\301!\207" [set-auto-mode t] 2])
  org-html-export-as-html(nil nil nil nil)
  org-export-dispatch(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-export-dispatch nil)
  call-interactively(org-export-dispatch nil nil)
  command-execute(org-export-dispatch)
```

Comment: Does it happen if you start with `emacs -q`? If not, something in your init file causes this. I tried it with org mode 9.1.9 and I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: I believe you mean `emacs -Q`. That loads up org version 8.2.10, which I clearly do not want.

Comment: If I blow away my `elpa` directory, start with `emacs -Q`, run `M-x package-list-packages`, install `org`, then I get version 9.1.14. If I quit emacs at that point, and restart with `emacs`, then try the `C-c C-e h H`, the conversion works and I get the title. So I think something was left over from a previous configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Carefully ensure that prior installations don't conflict with current installation.

In my case, the following cleared up the problem:

1. `rm -rf .emacs.d/elpa`
2. run `emacs -Q`
3. run `M-x package-list-packages`
4. install the org package; my installation offered me 9.1.14
5. quit emacs
6. run `emacs` -- my `init.el` file loads up other packages that were in the `elpa` directory
7. open the broken file, convert with `C-c C-e h H` to get the html buffer with no error and the title specified.